# Executing a function periodically on accurate and precise intervals

Tags: rust

I want to implement an accurate and precise countdown timer for my application. I started with the most simple implementation, which was not accurate at all.

```rust
loop {
    // Code which can take upto 10 ms to finish
    ...

    let interval = std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000);
    std::thread::sleep(interval);
}
```

As the code before the sleep call can take some time to finish, I cannot run the next iteration at the intended interval. Even worse, if the countdown timer is run for 2 minutes, the 10 milliseconds from each iteration add up to 1.2 seconds. So, this version is not very accurate.

I can account for this delay by measuring how much time this code takes to execute.

```rs
loop {
    let start = std::time::Instant::now();

    // Code which can take upto 10 ms to finish
    ...

    let interval = std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000);
    std::thread::sleep(interval - start.elapsed());
}
```

Even though this seems to precise up to milliseconds, I wanted to know if there is a way to implement this which is even more accurate and precise and/or how it is usually done in software.

Comment: My approach elsewhere is to sleep some fraction of the desired interval, then check the time. If the desired interval has passed, run the code, otherwise sleep and check again. If you sleep for, say, one tenth of the desired interval, you should be accurate to roughly interval/10. Reducing the sleep period will increase the accuracy. For ten-millisecond accuracy over two minutes, sleep for 10ms, check the time, etc. I do this in JavaScript. No idea how to do it in Rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For precise timing, you basically have to busy wait: `while time.elapsed() < interval {}`. This is also called "spinning" (you might have heard of "spin lock"). Of course, this is far more CPU intensive than using the OS-provided sleep functionality (which often transitions the CPU in some low power mode).

To improve upon that slightly, instead of doing absolutely nothing in the loop body, you could:

- Call [`thread::yield_now()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.yield_now.html).
- Call [`std::hint::spin_loop()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/hint/fn.spin_loop.html)

Unfortunately, I can't really tell you what timing guarantees these two functions give you. But from the documentation it seems like `spin_loop` will result in more precise timing.

Also, you very likely want to combine the "spin waiting" with `std::thread::sleep` so that you sleep the majority of the time with the latter method. That saves a lot of power/CPU-resources. And hey, there is even a crate for exactly that: [`spin_sleep`](https://crates.io/crates/spin_sleep). You should probably just use that.

Finally, just in case you are not aware: for several use cases of these "timings", there are other functions you can use. For example, if you want to render a frame every 60th of a second, you want to use some API that synchronizes your loop with the refresh rate/v-blanking of the monitor directly, instead of manually sleeping.